# Is this sentence (found on Wikipedia) correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence

On the [Wikipedia article on 'quiz'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiz), the first sentence states:

> A quiz is a form of game or mind sport, *attempt* to answer questions correctly.

I don't quite get the use of the word 'attempt' here. As a matter of fact, I don't understand how the entire part of the sentence after the comma (what is a word for such a subsentence?) makes sense in the context of the larger sentence. Is this sentence simply wrong, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is wrong. Maybe a few words such as _in which participants_ have accidentally been deleted.

Comment: A [deletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quiz&type=revision&diff=956673980&oldid=955803688) made earlier this year rendered the sentence ungrammatical. I began to restore it, but decided against touching the article— the whole thing is dreadful and needs a substantial rewrite for coherence.

Comment: @choster: Even so, the previous version is worth quoting: *"A quiz is a form of game or mind sport, in which the players (as individuals or in teams) attempt to answer questions correctly."*

Comment: The least it should be "....sport that attempts to answer questions correctly."

Answer (score 1):

This is not a grammatical sentence. It would be better for this sentence to say 'A quiz is a form of game or mind sport **in which participants** attempt to answer questions correctly'. The two changes I made were (1) removing the comma and (2) adding the bold-text words.

Comment: You need to bold *participants* too.